# Why does my regular expression not work in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

```
  if (!preg_match("/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,128}/", $password_1)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password does not match the requested format");
  }
```

The input for $password_1 is more than 128 characters, but it still results in true. But this expression works with the `<input>` tag in HTML i.e. `<input pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,128}" id="passwd" type="password" name="password_1" required="">`

But my doubt is: Why doesn't it work in PHP?

I could try not to use regex, and use manual if statements in php, but it feels like using this regex.

### INFORMATION:

I am not good at regex. Please help me with detail.

### AND:

I think that regex should match anything that is:

- Text more than 6 characters, and less than 128 characters including spaces and stuff
- A-Z and a-z and digits.
- Special characters

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the whole regex. Please help!!

Comment: I'm not very good either at Regexp, but that tool is : https://regex101.com/

Comment: max length is only limited to the substring... you don't limited your regexp to an entire string (eg. `/^ your regexp $/`) (^ is "from begin of line" $ is "until end of line")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your regex you are missing the start- and end-boundaries (`^` and `$`). Your current regex will just match the first 128 characters that matches your requirements and ignores the rest: https://regex101.com/r/ZLmRHq/1

However if you add the boundaries, you get

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,128}$/`

so the match should start at the beginning of the string, and end at the end of the string: https://regex101.com/r/ZLmRHq/3/

Comment: thanks a lot for that. I will test it in a few minutes. I use regexr.com now, and made `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*()]).{8,128}$` this regex, (obviously added `^` and `$` after your answer), to match the string only if atleast a single special character is present.

Comment: I will accept your answer temporarily for now until I test it. If it works, I will upvote it too :)